# Android JSONObject Conversion

Tags: android, json

I have a `JSON` file want to retrieve details from it and just display it in text view.
I get values for message and success but not for other i.e., student and details

**My JSON:**

```
{
"message":"Thank you for your patience.",
"student":{
    "name":"aaaa",
    "mark":"55",
    "dob":"10-09-1990"},
"details":{
    "fathername":"bbbb",
    "mothername":"ccccc",
    "address":"xxxxxx"},
"success":true
}
```

**My Java Code**

```
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
                // Getting JSON Array

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String success = json.getString("success"); // I get values for both of these 
                String message = json.getString("message");
                String StudentName = null;  

                // I Tried This/*
                user = json.getJSONArray("student");
                for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                    email = user.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");    
                }*/

                //Set JSON Data in TextView
                uid.setText(success);
                name1.setText(message);
                email1.setText(email);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

**I tried above code but get a error**

```
01-06 18:26:15.120: W/System.err(2110): org.json.JSONException: Value {"name":"aaaa","mark":"55","dob":"10-09-1990"} at student of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

student is a JSONObject and you have to manage it like a JSONObject. Change

```
 user = json.getJSONArray("student");
```

to

```
 JSONObject user = json.getJSONObject("student");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
user = json.getJSONArray("student");
```

student is not a jsonarray

```
"student":{
```

student is a jsononbject

So change

```
 JSONObject user = json.getJSONObject("student");
```

Then

```
 String name = user.getString("name");

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
 super.onPostExecute(json);  // missing
 // although this does not lead to any error
```

Comment: Is there any issue of not adding super class

Comment: @Prashanth nope. it is better to have that

Answer (score 0):

{
"message":"Thank you for your patience.",
"student":{
    "name":"aaaa",
    "mark":"55",
    "dob":"10-09-1990"},
"details":{
    "fathername":"bbbb",
    "mothername":"ccccc",
    "address":"xxxxxx"},
"success":true
}

Android Code :

```
JsonObject jsonobj = new JsonObject("your json String");
String message = jsonobj.getString("message");
String success = jsonobj.getString("success");

JsonObject studentObj = jsonobj.getJsonObject("student");
String name = studentObj.getString("name");
String mark= studentObj.getString("mark");

JsonObject detailsObj = jsonobj.getJsonObject("details");
String fathername= detailsObj.getString("fathername");
String mothername= detailsObj.getString("mothername");
```